# Does $\sum_{|k| \geq |x|} (1+|k-x|)^{-(n+1)} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

1. Does

> $$
> \sum_{\substack{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n \\ |k| \geq |x|}} \dfrac{1}{(1+|k-x|)^{n+1}} \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as} \quad |x| \rightarrow \infty?
> $$
>   
>   Follow-up Questions:

1. If so, how fast? For example, is the series $O(|x|^{-1})$?
2. What happens if $ \frac{1}{(1+t)^{n+1}} $ is replaced by something that decays more rapidly?

Easy Observations:

For each fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$
\sum_{\substack{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n \\ |k| \geq N}} \frac{1}{(1+|k-x|)^{n+1}} \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as} \quad N \rightarrow \infty.
$$
If the convergence is uniform in $x$, the answer to Question 1 is yes.

We also have
$$
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \frac{1}{(1+|k-x|)^{n+1}} < \infty.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No, obviously.

For every $x$ in $\mathbb Z^n$, the $k=x$ term in the series is $1$ hence the sum of the series is at least $1$, a fortiori it does not go to $0$ when $|x|\to\infty$.

(If $x$ is not in $\mathbb Z^n$, choose $k$ in $\mathbb Z^n$ such that $|k|\geqslant|x|$ and $|k-x|\leqslant1$ and adapt the argument.)